# Set sybase PHP library to return the same default date format as sqlserv

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sybase, date-formatting

I wrote an application in PHP that connects to a SQL server.
If this application runs on windows it uses **srvsql** libraries, in linux case it uses **sybase** libraries.
My trouble is that date fields outputs of sql server are not the same, with srvsql i get something like '**2012-12-10 12:14:26.067**'. With sybase i get '**Dec 10 2012 12:14:26:067PM** '!

How can i set sybase connection to get the SAME output format without changing every query?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP or the libraries you mention, but usually you should return a native binary `datetime` value from the server, then format it as you want in your PHP code. Is this possible in your situation?

Comment: I think the problem is the sybase library... if I print the raw values returned by sybase_fetch_array i get something like 'Dec 10 2012 12:14:26:067PM'!! I need an unique format for both windows library and linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a good solution to this for a few hours now myself. While I would love to handle this php side it just isn't an option in my current case as a 3rd party library is processing the data. The solution I just stumbled upon is on the query side.

The rough idea is convert the date to a string before the results are returned so the libraries (mssql and sqlsrv in my case) don't have the opportunity to muk with the results.

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(30), myDate, 121) AS date
```

121 is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

Other options can be found in Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

#### Edit

Found this the other day. Haven't experimented with it but the mssql library has a setting to tell it what to do with dates: `mssql.datetimeconvert = On`. There may be a way in php.ini to make both libraries render the date in the same format. I'm too far into the convert solution to switch over now but it would be worth some experimentation if someone is reading this for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about the date format that comes back from the different databases, consider handling it PHP-side.

Both of those formats, (`2012-12-10 12:14:26.067` and `Dec 10 2012 12:14:26:067PM`) are recognized by PHP.  When passed into a [DateTime object](http://php.net/class.datetime), they work as expected.  From the PHP interactive prompt:

```
php > $dt = new DateTime('Dec 10 2012 12:14:26:067PM');
php > echo $dt->format('r u'), "\n";
Mon, 10 Dec 2012 12:14:26 -0800 067000
php >
php > $dt = new DateTime('2012-12-10 12:14:26.067');
php > echo $dt->format('r u'), "\n";
Mon, 10 Dec 2012 12:14:26 -0800 067000
```

If you need a [refresher](http://php.net/date), `r` is the format code for an RFC 2822 date, while `u` is the format code for microseconds, which only work with DateTimes.

By switching to DateTimes, you can easily juggle between input formats and basically never have to worry about it.  DateTime uses the [`strtotime` parsing rules](http://php.net/datetime.formats).  You'll want to understand their limitations, but you generally won't bump up against them.

Comment: I'd love some constructive feedback to go with that downvote.